# SVG - графика

Tags: svg

Почему не работает этот пример?
Круг снизу не прорисован и данные не отображаются.

```
<svg>
<circle cx="102" cy="102" r="100" fill="rgb(234,234,234)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)">
</svg>
```

P.S. а jsfiddle.net у всех теперь не работает? Не даёт сохранить код и пускает кольца О_о?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@I_CaR](/users/3547/i_car), вы забыли указать высоту и ширину для SVG элемента. Вот так все **[работает](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxmfF)**:

```
<svg height="204" width="204">
    <circle cx="102" cy="102" r="100" fill="rgb(234,234,234)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

**p.s.** да, jsFiddle мне тоже не дает сохранить код.